# Deleting mysql related records with specific count

Tags: mysql

I need to delete records in table 'people' that were created before 2012, that belong to hotel id '1', and that only have 1 record in related table 'taskinstance'.  The tables are related this way: people.id = taskinstance.idClient. I come up with the following which gives me a syntax error.

```
DELETE people FROM taskinstance people 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM taskinstance
    WHERE substring(people.dateCreated,1,4) < 2012 and people.idHotel = '1'  
     GROUP BY taskinstance.idClient 
     HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) taskinstance 
ON people.id = taskinstance.idClient
```

If I just want to view the records, the following works :

```
SELECT *
FROM people
INNER JOIN taskinstance ON people.id = taskinstance.idClient
WHERE substring(people.dateCreated,1,4) < 2012 and people.idHotel = '1'
GROUP BY people.id
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try something like this:</strike>

```
 DELETE FROM people WHERE people.id IN 
 (SELECT people.id
 FROM people
 INNER JOIN taskinstance ON people.id = taskinstance.idClient
 WHERE substring(people.dateCreated,1,4) < 2012 and people.idHotel = '1'
 GROUP BY people.id
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Edit: tested on my own database, this one was refused for having the same table in the WHERE clause as in the DELETE clause.

Or this:

```
 DELETE people FROM people
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT people.id
    FROM people
    INNER JOIN taskinstance ON people.id = taskinstance.idClient
    WHERE substring(people.dateCreated,1,4) < 2012 and people.idHotel = '1'
    GROUP BY taskinstance.idClient
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) p
 ON p.id = people.id
```

Edit: I tested an almost-identical query to this one in my own database (just with my own tables), and there were no syntax errors in the query.

Please post the full text of your syntax error so that we can track down the problem, especially the part where it says, `"... for the right syntax to use near 'something something something' on line X."`  The `something something` part is the most important part for troubleshooting.  For example, if it says `"near '' on line 6"` then you have almost certainly not escaped your single quotes around that 1.

Comment: "They don't work" is not specific enough to figure out how to tweak them. What exact syntax error are you getting, or is nothing being deleted at all?

Comment: Sorry about that : it's the same syntax error I was getting, "ERROR 1064"... Thanks again.      Fred

Comment: See my edits.  I need the full text of the error in order to track down which spot it's stopping at.